# Does Krebs cycle occur in fast glycolytic muscle fibres?

Tags: muscles, mitochondria

They have mitochondria. So they can have aerobic respiration. (?)

Does Krebs cycle occur in their mitochondria?

Comment: Could you please clarify. What do you mean by an “effective” enzyme, and inhibited under what circumstances. The enzymes of the Krebs Tricarboxylic Acid cycle are located in the mitochondria, so their total activity in a cell will obviously depend on the number of mitochondria. But surely that isn’t your question.

Comment: @David Our examiner used this term "effective" just the way I put it in the quesion. So effective, how? I don't know either. 
But I think we should consider all enzymes that somehow take part in Krebs cycle.
So as you said I think we should consider the enzymes that are located in the mitochondria.
Does aerobic respiration and Krebs cycle occur in white muscle cells?
If they do, then these enzymes are active in mitochondria of white muscles as well as red muscles, but the number of these effective enzymes are fewer in white muscle cells.

Comment: The point of mitochondria is aerobic respiration using the TCA cycle, the electron transport chain, and generation of ATP by oxidative phosphorylation. Different muscles types in different species vary in the extent their action can be sustained by a supply of oxygen, so they vary in their content of mitochondria. Although for teaching purposes it is useful to contrast extreme fast-twitch and slow-twitch muscles, there is no requirement for a muscle to be completely anaerobic. Those mitochondria that are present can use that oxygen (and substrates) that are available.